# How to delay downgrading a Braintree Subscription

Tags: python, payment-gateway, payment, braintree, subscription

I want to downgrade users' monthly subscription while letting them to use the original plan until the end of current billing period. I need to know the original `plan_id` but [Subscription.find()](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/subscription/find/python) return the downgraded `plan_id`. How can I get the original `plan_id`. Must I store it in DB? Can I get this form Braintree?

**Example**
With Braintree `Subscription.create()` I subscript to the plan `premium` at 1 march, with monthly subscription. At 3 March, I downgrade it to plan `basic` with [Subscription.update()](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/subscription/update/python). We want our system to allow me to use `premium` features until the end of March. At 4 march, I login and the system queries `Subscription.find(sub_id)` to get `plan_id` to check whether I am still using plan `premium` . But, as far as i know, the `plan` in the subscription response object would be `basic`. How can the system know I am entitled to use `premium` until the end of march? Can Braintree API return this information (i.e. premium plan)?

Comment: For `downgrade users' monthly subscription while letting them to use the original plan until the end of current billing period`,  are there better way to do this other than the above way of `Subscription.update()`.

Comment: I have one way for it: 
1) update the current subscription to make it expire at the end of current billing period (using `number_of_billing_cycles =  current_billing_cycle`) and
2) create a new subscription which start billing from the start of next cycle

Comment: Did you ever find a better way than having to create a second subscription?